# Do I need quote marks when I quote myself?

Tags: quotes, quotations, quotation-marks

Hello language lovers,

English isn't my first language and I would like to know if I need to use quotation marks when I quote something I said in the past.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? For example, are you trying to say something like this: "Remember that time I asked, 'Do i need quote marks when i quote myself?'"

Comment: Lets get those i in the titles to I's.

Comment: Exactly @JakeRegier ! so you would put single quotes instead of doubles ?

Comment: No, because I was hypothetically quoting you. You would write it like this: *Remember that time I asked, "Do i need quote marks when i quote myself?"* (No italics necessary.) The reason I originally enclosed the quotation in single quotation marks is because it is a [quotation within a quotation](http://www.scribendi.com/advice/when_to_use_double_or_single_quotation_marks.en.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The subject of the quote doesn't have any bearing on whether or not to use quote marks. You should use quotation marks when you are quoting someone word-for-word, like this:

> I said, "You should do it."

You don't have to use them with indirect quotes like this:

> I said that he should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you quote someone else, you use *quotation marks* to indicate that those are the exact words of the speaker. (Otherwise, it might be considered plagiarism in academic circles.)

But when you recall what you said, you would normally say it as follows:

That was back in 1990. You said you were getting married in December. And, I wished you all the best. We went our separate ways. - No quotation marks here, whosoever!

I said: "All the best!" - *Direct speech*

Or you may write: Here's what I said: "All the best!"

Comment: Generally when you use quotation marks it’s to indicate that these words are an exact transcription of what was said regardless of who said them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - after all, you are part of the conversation.

> She asked me, 'How are you?' and I replied, 'Good, thank you.'